# How to debug bash expansion?

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to figure out why bash autocompletion on filesystem is slow on my PC. My Linux machine is connected to an AD through PAM and I am suspecting bash is trying to query a network mount (which is slow since it queries PAM) every time I use TAB for autocomplete.

I have tried `set -x` and when I do autocomplete on `/var` the slowest operation is the following line:

```
[[ /var == ~* ]]
```

Also, the following line takes a few seconds to execute in bash when I am connected to the network whereas it returns immediately if it is not connected:

```
TEMP=~*
```

I would like to know what bash is trying to expand `~*` to or find a workaround.

Comment: If you want to know if it's a _literal_ tilde, `[[ $foo = "~"* ]]` would be a much faster operation than `[[ $foo = ~* ]]`. Even if you want to keep tilde expansion in place, `[[ $foo = ~/* ]]` would be faster as well, as it would only be looking at whether it's under *your* home directory.

Comment: By the way, you might consider setting a `PS4` that includes both file and line number, so you can look at the faulty code in-context. For instance: `PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+'` will give you the source file and line of each command run.

Comment: Does `getent passwd` take a comparably long time to that comparison?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: It is not specific to a file or directory. It consistently slow on all files/directories. I need to know if there is a way to know what the bash is trying to expand the ~* to.

Comment: @EtanReisner: `getent passwd` is pretty fast, because it is cached locally.

Comment: @Hooman, did I say it was specific to any file or directory?

Comment: If you want to see what `~*` expands to, it's easy to ask the shell: `printf '%s\n' ~*`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Does that expand to something for you? I just get `~*` back here. Which, I suppose, makes sense since `*` is going to fail to be a login name but I can't see why that would take any time (if it isn't the user list fetching).

Comment: Is the tab expansion slow every time or just occasionally? What sort of magnitude of slowness is happening on that line?

Comment: @EtanReisner, if I actually cared enough to do research on this one, I'd be using strace, ltrace, sysdig, &c. to watch the actual underlying work.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Absolutely, mostly just trying to find out if you were actually seeing it expand to something since I don't see it do that and by my reading of `Tilde Expansion` it shouldn't be doing anything but checking for possible usernames (which could take a while in some cases but I would have expected, perhaps incorrectly, that `getent` would also take a while in that case. <shrug>

Comment: I found a workaround. I am using Ubuntu 14.10 and modified the line in /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion and commented out this line `elif [[ $1 == ~* ]]; then`. It is probably not a perfect solution but seems to resolve the delay for me!

Answer (score 0):

trying running it with strace
for example
strace echo $FOO
if the system is accessing your mount, you will know